# How do I accept an answer here in Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

I can't find any vestige on how to accept an answer. I had some good answer on my Questions and I must accept 'em, but I can't find where is this feature.
Thanks in  advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1):

Look left from this post.
There is a Check mark, click on it to accept answer.

Comment: As this question is going to be closed soon, I am not sure the OP will be able to accept any answer to this question. This would make this answer more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Holy cow! How could I be so damn blind? This is embarrassing. Sorry and Thanks!!!

Comment: :D An answer simply stating that the questioner can accept their answer, and it was actually legitimate. That deserves the + rep! (although, I didn't upvote it..)

Comment: @Complicatedseebio closed question means no further answers can be posted, but existing answers can be voted on and accepted as usual. Nothing confusing here.